# Redirect from old page to new page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect from `contactus.php` to `contactus.html` using `.htaccess` file with below rule. But not working for me and tried with google solutions, still not working.

**Solution 1**

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule 301 www.domain.com/contactus.php www.domain.com/contactus.html
```

**Solution 2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contactus.php$ www.domain.com/contactus.html[L,R=301]
```

**Both are not working for me**.

Can you please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

if your new page is contact.html then in htaccess file you are using [www.domain.com/contactus.html](http://www.domain.com/contactus.html) which should be [www.domain.com/contact.html](http://www.domain.com/contact.html)

Comment: Hello Kei, My contact page is `contactus.html` not `contact.html`.

Comment: oh as in description its was contact.html that is why I thought you are making a mistake in htaccess

Comment: Sorry, mistaken.